# Store Azure Key Vault clientSecret securely

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

I'm working on a C# desktop application (a plugin for a 3D modelling software) and from this I need to access info from a GraphQL endpoint. In order to access the endpoint I need to provide a secret key. So what I've done is to store that key on Azure Key Vault.
And this is the code I'm using to get the key from Azure Key Vault:

```
var clientProd = new SecretClient(new Uri("my-azure-keyvault-url"),
  new ClientSecretCredential(
    "tenantId",
    "clientId",
    "clientSecret"));

Response<KeyVaultSecret> secret = await clientProd.GetSecretAsync("cbe-graphQL-prod");
```

But now I'm finding myself in this sort of vicious loop, where I'm not sure where that clientSecret should come from so it's not pushed to version control.
I'm going to deploy this application to multiple users in my company, so I wouldn't want to create an environment variable on everyone's machine (not even with a group policy).

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you asking about client secret of Desktop application where is originally found or want to know to to pass that secret from keyVault if it store there?

Comment: I want to store (out of code and/or version control) that "clientSecret" string that I need to access Azure Key Vault

Answer (score 2):

If you are hosting your application in Azure, you can use **System Assigned Managed Identity** to access the key vault without any credentials (client id, client secret)

If your application is hosted on premises, you can limit the access of the app registration (service principal) to the key vault in which secret is stored.

Then you can either store the client secret as environment variable or hard code the client secret

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my app isn't actually stored anywhere as it is a desktop application, not web...

Comment: you can store the client secret in a separate file and make use of gitignore in your case

Comment: Would the secret get compiled in the dll if you do that? Because I thought of that, but then I also thought that when I deploy the application to my colleagues they wouldn't be able to query the db because the secret wasn't on their machine...

Comment: You can use Azure AD authentication for your key vault : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/storing-and-using-secrets-in-azure/